# Can i set a variable in docker compose and use it more than once for more clear code?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

Can I set a variable in docker-compose yml file for more clear code ?

For example if there is a value that I use more than once and I want to keep it with one declaration

Like :

```
version: '2.4'
ValueToPassFromVariable: '2020-10-10 12:00:00'

services:
  img1:
     image: img1
     build:
       context: .
       args:
         - STARTDATE=ValueToPassFromVariable
       dockerfile: DockerFileImg1
       
  img2:
     image: img2
     build:
       context: .
       args:
         - STARTDATE=ValueToPassFromVariable
       dockerfile: DockerFileImg2
```

I want to save some value in `ValueToPassFromVariable` and use it few time, can i do something like this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you update to a newer version of docker-compose, you can get generic reuse by using [extension fields](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields):

```yaml
version: "3.8"

x-args: &args
  args:
    - STARTDATE=2020-10-10 12:00:00

services:
  img1:
     image: img1
     build:
       context: .
       << : *args
       dockerfile: DockerFileImg1
       
  img2:
     image: img2
     build:
       context: .
       << : *args
       dockerfile: DockerFileImg2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Create .env file and put it to the docker-compose root directory.
   Example of .env file:

```
STARTDATE=value
```

2. Add environment variable directly to build machine with command

For linux

```
export STARTDATE=value
```

For Windows

```
setx STARTDATE value
```

After that in docker-compose you need to use this value.

Example:

```
version: '2.4'
ValueToPassFromVariable: '2020-10-10 12:00:00'

services:
  img1:
     image: img1
     build:
       context: .
       args:
         - STARTDATE=${STARTDATE}
       dockerfile: DockerFileImg1
       
  img2:
     image: img2
     build:
       context: .
       args:
         - STARTDATE=${STARTDATE}
       dockerfile: DockerFileImg2
```

See [the `docker-compose` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) for more details.

Comment: Maybe the second option can be useful for me, but generally I want somethings just to save the variable and not to write its value twice, I don't want to set variables in my machine even though it can be a good idea.

Comment: If you don't want to set env variables on your machine you can create .env file in your project and use it instead setting env variables.

Comment: Yes of course, it also maybe a good for some cases but for it was something that is more related just to syntax and to make more simple code, it don't want to make real changes in other files